# How order multtiples key and value in dictonary python

Tags: python, list

I have the following code:

```
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

for i in range(len(dragonLoot) ):
    inv[i] = dragonLoot[i] `
```

and when I add list to dictionary I get this in OUTPUT:

```
  {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1, 0: 'gold coin', 1: 'dagger', 2: 'gold        coin',3: 'gold coin', 4:'ruby'}
```

and I don't know how to compare this key in one key and value in one value .

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I think they want to add the counts of the dragon loot items to the dictionary

Comment: i want connect gold coin in one gold coin and other in one without repetition

Comment: exacly 'gold coin' : 45

Answer (score 1):

To add to existing counts and add new ones, consider something like:

```
for i in range(len(dragonLoot)):
    currentLoot = dragonLoot[i]
    if currentLoot in inv:
        inv[currentLoot] = inv[currentLoot] + 1
    else:
       inv[currentLoot] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Several issues.  Don't iterage over len of your list or i will be a number not a string.  Next, you'll be attempting to address a dict key that doesn't exist when you get to dagger, so you need to handle that exception.

```
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

for i in dragonLoot:
    try:
        inv[i] += 1
    except KeyError:
        inv[i] = 1
```

Comment: You don't need the `try/except`, you could simply do `inv[i] = inv.get(i, 0) + 1`